# div same as tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

you helped me yesterday with create tooltip div. Today i would like to extend it.
I have something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/Axjgf/18/

How can I change it so that the yellow box appears next to the box that I clicked on? For instance if I click on the purple box it should appear next to the purple box instead of the black.

thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/genesis/VmXU9/26/

Comment: look on it little bit more. http://jsfiddle.net/genesis/TZ9Nt/1/ what's not working?

Comment: ok thanks. and how can i set the left value like top value automatic?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the last example here: [Query-Click Doc](http://api.jquery.com/click/). Use $(this) for getting the clicked div attributes.

Comment: but how does it apply for me?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the color of the overlay box, you can give each smaller box its own click utility.

**EDIT:**

Just realized you wanted a position change! ;-)  Code is fixed.  See below.

```
   $("#TWO").click(
        function()
        {
            $("#THREE").toggle().css({'opacity' : '0.8', 'backgroundColor' : 'blue', 'top' : '-320px'});

        });

    $("#five").click(
        function()
        {
            $("#THREE").toggle().css({'opacity' : '0.8', 'backgroundColor' : 'purple', 'top' : '-280px'});

        });

    $("#six").click(
        function()
        {
            $("#THREE").toggle().css({'opacity' : '0.8', 'backgroundColor' : 'yellow', 'top' : '-220px'});

        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Axjgf/21/

**EDIT 2:**

Since the question changed, I edited the fiddle, to remove the background color change.

```
$("#TWO").click(
    function()
    {
        $("#THREE").toggle().css({'opacity' : '0.8', 'top' : '-320px'});

    });

$("#five").click(
    function()
    {
        $("#THREE").toggle().css({'opacity' : '0.8', 'top' : '-280px'});

    });

$("#six").click(
    function()
    {
        $("#THREE").toggle().css({'opacity' : '0.8', 'top' : '-220px'});

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Axjgf/22/

Comment: thanks, but for example the new DIV BLUE is with div black. should be with old DIV BLUE :) need edited the css:     position:relative;
    top: -220px;
    left:50px; but how?

Comment: @Gisinior. Do you want the position of the boxes to change or the color or both?  I changed the color and the position, so that the new boxes (blue and purple) appear at the same position as the yellow appears with the black, which is what I gathered from the question.

Comment: To further explain, I placed the popup boxes in the middle of the smaller boxes, which is what happens for the original black and yellow combo.

Comment: Is this what you mean... *How can I change it so that the yellow box appears next to the box that I clicked on? For instance if I click on the purple box it should appear next to the purple box instead of the black.*  I just saw it in your edited question.

Comment: sorry :) my mistake :) this work ok :) but what if i add new div? or if i enlargements div?  then doesn work. here is good example with tooltip:  http://www.queness.com/resources/html/tooltip/jquery-tooltip-queness.html I would like similarly.

Comment: how do to the value of TOP and LEFT were dependent on the clicked div and not from the main div?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery, I would highly recommend using the jQuery UI library's ["Position" utility](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/).

It has quite a few useful little methods for aligning objects relative to another object. For example using that library you could modify your click function to something like this (untested):

```
$('.click').click(function(){
    $(c) = $(this);
    $('#THREE').position({
        my: 'left top',
        at: 'right center',
        of: $(c)
    });
});
```

Comment: @Gisinior - I went ahead and added an example so you can see how it might look.